# Driver for Lenovo PCI-E graphics card ADD2-R

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics

Installing Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit desktop on an old Lenovo ThinkCentre A57

There is a simple grapics card inside the box, marked Lenovo ADD2-R
On the card is only one chip, marked CONEXANT CX25904-13Z

The graphics board is not recognized at install, it is running now at 1024x768, at this resolution it fucntions correctly. I would like to have 1280 x 1024 resolution.

I have found nothing so far on the net about this card or this chip. Conexant seems to be more about audio.

Is there an Ubuntu 14.04 driver for this graphics card?